# Как в pyhon зашифровать файл побайтово?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, байты

Есть код:

```
import os

key = [0xA3, 0xBD, 0xAD, 0x0D, 0x41, 0x11, 0xBB, 0x8D, 0xDC, 0x80, 0x2D, 0xD0, 0xD2, 0xC4, 0x9B, 0x1E, 0x26, 0xEB, 0xE3, 0x33, 0x4A, 0x15, 0xE4, 0x0A, 0xB3, 0xB1, 0x3C, 0x93, 0xBB, 0xAF, 0xF7, 0x3E]

fi = open("1.bin", "rb")
fo = open("1e .bin", "wb")
length = os.path.getsize("1.bin")
position = 0
try:
    while position < length:
        byte = fi.read(1)
        if position >= 320 and position < 31040:
            byte = chr(ord(byte) ^ key[position & 31])
        fo.write(byte)
        position += 1
finally:
    fi.close()
    fo.close()
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Но как можно увидеть мы считываем байт, шифруем его через XOR и пытаемся записать в другой файл...

В чем же проблема и как исправить?

Спасибо

Comment: у меня все работает нормально - ошибок нет, новый файл создался, состав идентичен исходному файлу. В `bin` переименовал обычный `txt`. Делал в PyCharm. Попробуйте так сделать для начала.

Comment: chr возвращает строку, а у вас файл открыт в бинарном виде, видимо пример от второго питона, а у вас третий

Comment: На всякий случай - если это не просто потренироваться, а рабочий код, то шифрование повторяющимся ксором очень слабое, лучше взять готовые проверенные способы типа aes-256

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan,  что это значит? У меня все на 3.10 работает.

Comment: @Сергей у вас всё сработало потому вы, вероятно, создали `1.bin` маленького объема текста. в данном коде шифруются символы на позициях `320 - 31040`

Comment: В общем-то достаточно даже просто через mypy код прогнать, и он сразу эту ошибку выдаст

Comment: @n1tr0xs, да, верно, спасибо (и за ответ). Да и автор вопроса мог сам проверить причину простым `print (type (byte))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно преобразовать ваш зашифрованный символ в байты.

```
if position >= 320 and position < 31040:
    byte = chr(ord(byte) ^ key[position & 31])
    byte = bytes(byte, encoding='utf-8')
```

Или можно сократить:

```
if position >= 320 and position < 31040:
    byte = bytes(chr(ord(byte) ^ key[position & 31]), encoding='utf-8')
```

UPD:
Я бы еще заменил `while` на `for`:

```
for position in range(length):
    byte = fi.read(1)
    if position >= 320 and position < 31040:
        byte = bytes(chr(ord(byte) ^ key[position & 31]), encoding='utf-8')
    fo.write(byte)
```